# output of an if loop in different templates python

Tags: python

My project is about shape detection, I have to detect the different rectangle in a given image and then import these data into a .qml file, I've been able to do so, but the problem is that the output in the console(I'm using Spyder) is n templates (.qml) with n is the number of the rectangles in the image, and in my folder there is only one .qml file ( the last one in the console)

I don't knw where is my mistake.
U'll find below an extract of my code:

```
    if shape == "rectangle":
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),0)
        myfile.write('The cordinations of the rectangle are :\n')
        myfile.write('x : '+str(x)+'\n')
        myfile.write('y : '+str(y)+'\n')
        myfile.write('width : '+str(w)+'\n')
        myfile.write('height : '+str(h)+'\n')
        # Open template file and pass string to 'data'.
        # Will be in QML syntax except with the string.Template replace tags
        # with the format of '$var'. The 'var' MUST correspond to the items
        # that will be calculated (i.e. coordinates, sizes, ids, etc.)
        with open('cordinations.txt', 'r') as my_template:
            data = my_template.read()
            # Print template for visual cue.
            print('Template loaded:')
            print(data)
            # Pass 'data' to string.Template object data_template.
            data_template = string.Template(data)             

            cordinates=[]
            cordinates.append(dict(abscisse=x,ordonee=y,width=w,height=h))
            t=Template("""
        x: $abscisse
        y: $ordonee
        w: $width
        h: $height
        """)
            print "    Rectangle:"
            print("      {")
            for data in cordinates:
                print (t.substitute(data))
                print("      }")

                # Open QML output file and fill its contents by string substitution
            with open("main.qml", 'w') as output_file:
                # Run string.Template substitution on data_template
                # using data from 'values' as source and write to 'output_file'.
                output_file.write('import QtQuick 2.2')
                output_file.write('\nItem')
                output_file.write("  \n{")
                output_file.write("   id:\n")
                output_file.write('   height: '+str(height)+'\n')
                output_file.write('   width: '+str(width)+'\n')
                if shape == 'rectangle':
                    output_file.write('  \n\n  Rectangle')
                    output_file.write("   \n   {")
                    output_file.write('    \n            id:')
                    output_file.write(t.substitute(data))
                    output_file.write("}")
                    output_file.write("\n}")
                output_file.close()
            #    Print QML generated code for visual cue.
            with open('main.qml', 'r') as my_qml:
                qml_code = my_qml.read()
                print('QML code generated:')
                print(qml_code)

    # show the output image
    cv2.imshow("Shapes", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Thank u for ur time and ur help

Comment: First `if` is not a loop, its a condition

Comment: Small note: you don't need to close file descriptor manually (`output_file.close()`) in a `with`-scope. It will be done automatically when you leave the scope.

Comment: Thank u for the clarification, I tried ur solution, but I got this error :  ` with shape=='rectangle': `
`AttributeError: __exit__ `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `'a'` (append) instead of `'w'` (write) in your

`with open("main.qml", 'w') as output_file:`